# How to wrap a piece of text in a html document with a new span using Java

Tags: java, xml

Using Java, I would like to find an element using xpath in a HTML document. Once found, I would like to add a span around the text with a style to highlight the text.

Is this something that could be done using Java?

**Example:**

***From:***

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>hello</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

***To:***

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><span class="colorRed">hello</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Depends if it is a one off on that small snippet, or if you have many of these to do in a big document. What is your use case?

Comment: I have many to do in a HTML document. @Bentaye

Comment: The use-case is to highlight pieces of text to a user.

Comment: Then I'd say use a DOM manipulation library such as `jsoup` (https://jsoup.org)

Comment: Might be quicker to do manually, especially if there's no singular way to identify the text you want to span.